# Why ternary condition defined inside an object is not applied when the object is invoked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm on the learning phase of react, I have defined an object full of inline styles with ternary operator condition,But its not working at all! could some one help me how to achieve this please

```
import React from 'react';

function Joke(props)
{
    const styles = {
    fontSize: "30px",
 display: props.question && props.answer ? "block" : "none",
 display: props.punchline ? "block" : "none",
 color: !props.question && "#888888"
  }
    return(
        <div>
    <p className="qus" style={styles}> {props.jokes.question} </p>
     <p className="ans" style={styles}> {props.jokes.answer} </p>
        <p className="punch" style={styles}> {props.jokes.punchline} </p>
        </div>

    )
}

export default Joke

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------*/

import React from 'react';
import Joke from "./Joke"

function App()
{



    return (
        <div>
        <Joke jokes={{
            question:"who is the president",
            answer:"Trump"}} />

        <Joke jokes={{
                 punchline: "hey look there is no question and answer here but there is no space been taken by those"}} />
        <Joke  jokes={{
            question:"what is 1+1",
            answer:"11"}}/> 

         </div>    
    )
}
export default App
```

In some scenarios, i'm sending object with question and answer and in some scenarios i'm just sending in a punchline instead of question and answer, Could some one tell me if there is a way to set a ternary condition inside object so it gets applied every time, when i pass props object as parameter to the Joke function

Comment: You'd have to make the property have getter/setter methods. The object initializer expressions only run once otherwise.

Comment: @Pointy Could you please elaborate with an example, im a student learning coding and just started react today... any help from you at this point would help me understand deeper

Comment: OK. Also, having the same property name twice does not make sense. There can only be one value for a given property name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you really want is to conditionally render the `<p>`aragraphs based on properties of `props.jokes`, like so:

```js
function Joke(props) {
  const styles = {
    fontSize: 30,
    color: !props.jokes.question && '#888'
  }
  return (
    <div>
      {props.jokes.question && <p className='qus' style={styles}>{props.jokes.question}</p>}
      {props.jokes.answer && <p className='ans' style={styles}>{props.jokes.answer}</p>}
      {props.jokes.punchline && <p className='punch' style={styles}>{props.jokes.punchline}</p>}
    </div>
  )
}
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Joke jokes={{
        question: 'who is the president',
        answer: 'Trump'}} />
      <Joke jokes={{
        punchline: 'hey look there is no question and answer here but there is no space been taken by those(?)'}} />
      <Joke jokes={{
        question: 'what is 1+1',
        answer: '11'}} />
    </div>
  )
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "getter" function:

```
const styles = {
  fontSize: "30px",
  get display() {
    return props.question && props.answer || props.punchline ? "block" : "none";
  },
  get color() {
    return !props.question && "#888888"
  }
};
```

Note that this will only have an effect like what you want if something, somewhere changes the contents of that `props` object. If that never changes, you're kind-of out of luck with a setup like this.

Comment: `const styles` is in OP's functional component though. Its initialiser object literal is already evaluated on each rerender so should already be correct

Comment: @ᆼᆺᆼ wow your username is interesting to `@` :)  Yes I realize that; I confess to not really understanding what the OP wants or whether it's even possible.

Comment:  Looking at it now not only are there two `display:` properties but OP is checking `props.question` etc. but should really be `props.jokes.question`